# Convex function is left-hand and right-hand differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've come across a proof on ProofWiki [(link here)](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Convex_Real_Function_is_Left-Hand_and_Right-Hand_Differentiable) which aims to show that a convex function $f$ is left-hand and right-hand differentiable on an open interval $(a,b)$. It uses that convex function inequality to show that the function $$F(h) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$ for $x \in (a, b)$ is increasing on an interval $(0, \delta)$ for some $\delta > 0$. However, the article proceeds by making the claim that from the Theorem of Limit of Increasing Function, it follows that the function $F$ has a left-hand and right-hand limit in $0$. But from my understanding of the cited theorem, this claim is not trivial because $0 \notin (0, \delta).$ The Limit of Increasing Function only claims that if $F$ is increasing on an open interval $(a,b)$, then $F$ has a a right-hand and left-hand limit for every point INSIDE the interval $(a,b)$.

My first instinct is to doubt my judgement because the proof is provided with citations and a flawed article probably wouldn't be allowed to stay on the site. So what am I missing? I would greatly appreciate if anyone could point the error in my reasoning. If I happen to be right, how should the proof be continued?
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: It is unclear to me what your doubt is. If $x \in (a, b)$ then $[x, x+\delta) \subset (a, b)$ for some $\delta > 0$. $F(h)$ is defined and decreasing on $(0, \delta)$, so that $\lim_{h\to 0+} F(h)$ exists. That limit is the right derivative of $f$ at $x$.

Comment: @MartinR How is that true? If $F(h) = -\frac{1}{h}$, then it is defined and increasing on $(0, \delta)$, but $\lim_{h\to 0+} F(h)$ doesnt exist.

Comment: The first inequality in that article shows that $F$ is bounded below.

Comment: @MartinR I see, so this proves that $\lim_{h\to 0+} F(h)$ does exist. But what about $\lim_{h\to 0-} F(h)$?

Comment: Its the same. For negative $h$ is $F(h)$ increasing and bounded above.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah you're right. I kinda misunderstood the article. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are plenty of flawed articles on ProofWiki, which is appallingly unreliable, and tantamount to useless. In this particular case, the page quotes K.G. Binmore's "Mathematical Analysis: A Straightforward Approach" Theorem 12.14 practically word for word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof in the referenced article is correct, but does not mention explicitly that both monotony and boundedness is used to prove the existence of the one-sided limits.

The precise argument goes as follows: For $x \in (a, b)$ we can choose a $\delta > 0$ such that $(x-\delta, x+\delta) \subset(a, b)$. The convexity condition then implies that
$$
\frac{f(x+h_1) - f(x)}{h_1} \le\frac{f(x+h_2) - f(x)}{h_2} \le \frac{f(x+k_1) - f(x)}{k_1} \le \frac{f(x+k_2) - f(x)}{k_2}
$$
for $-\delta < h_1 < h_2 < 0 < k_1 < k_2 < \delta$.

This shows that $\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ is

- increasing and bounded above on $(-\delta, 0)$, so that $\lim_{h \to 0-}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f'_-(x)$ exists, and
- increasing and bounded below on $(0, \delta)$,  so that $\lim_{h \to 0+}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f'_+(x)$ exists.

It also shows that the limits satisfy $f'_-(x) \le f'_+(x)$.